# How to recover Google account without username or Gmail address?

Tags: google-contacts

I forgot my username and Gmail address. I had to get new mobile phone with a new number. How do I recover my account?

Answer (score 0):

you can go through these links to see if you can get your google account back :

[google account recovery - link 1](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/)

[google account recovery - link 2](https://support.google.com/talk/answer/23986?hl=en)